# Is it always necessary to restart IIS after installing an ISAPI filter?

Tags: windows, iis, isapi

Is it necessary to restart IIS when installing a new ISAPI filter?

Always?  Sometimes?  When?

I'd appreciate documentation links, if you have 'em.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are adding a filter at the site level, a restart is not required - but you do need to make at least 1 request to the website for the filter to "load".

If you are adding a filter at the global level, a restart is required.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/54c41c83-3723-4695-9bf1-9f7b1f674be0.mspx?mfr=true

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317204